# How see if the client aborted the request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying do a mp4 converter, but if the client cancel the request, continues the conversion, how I stop the conversion if the client cancel the request?

Code from conversor:

```
    // Start the ffmpeg child process
    const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
    // Remove ffmpeg's console spamming
    '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
    // Redirect/Enable progress messages
    '-progress', 'pipe:3',
    // Set inputs
    '-i', 'pipe:4',
    '-i', 'pipe:5',
    // Map audio & video from streams
    '-map', '0:a',
    '-map', '1:v',
    // Keep encoding
    '-c:v', 'copy',
    // Define output file
    token + formato,
  ], {
    windowsHide: true,
    stdio: [
      /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
      'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
      /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
      'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'
    ],
  });

  ffmpegProcess.stdio[3].on('data', (err) => {
    console.log(res.status())
  });
  
  audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
  video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[5]);
  
  ffmpegProcess.stdio[6].on('error', (err) => {
    // Remover token do objeto
    delete inUseTokens[token];
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  });

  ffmpegProcess.stdio[6].on('close', () => {
    console.log("convertido!")
    res.render('downloated', {formato: formato, title: titulo, token: token, thumbnail: thumbnail, seconds: seconds})
    })
  });
```

I don't know how I can solve this...

Comment: I think you should provide more context, where is being executed this code shell or http server or....? what you might probably need is to wrap your code, listen and process.exit(code=0)

Comment: When the user cancels you could try
 `ffmpegProcess.kill('SIGHUP')`

Comment: @Keith i tried but have a error "Error: kill ENOSYS"...

Comment: @koalaok i'm using in a http server

Comment: Is this on windows?  Try SIGINT instead..

Comment: @Keith i tried and another error, but is “write EPIPE” :(

Comment: Yes, that error is what you want, if you check your processes you will see `ffmpeg` is terminated, you just need to handle the error as you have now force closed the pipe.